# Задача не проходит именно один тест, помогите понять причину

Tags: python, python-3.x

Проходит большинство тестов, но на одном застывает, условие: http://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=293. В чем может быть проблема, какие входные данные я мог не учесть?

```
a = int(input())
b = list(map(int, input().split()))
c = list(map(int, input().split()))
n = max = e = 0
while a > 0:
if b[e] * c[e] > max:
    max = b[e] * c[e]
    n = e + 1
a -= 1
e += 1
print(n)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код выдаёт неправильный результат для случая, когда все фирмы платят по 0 рублей налогов. В этом случае правильный ответ должен быть 1, а у вас 0.

<strike>Вынесите n = e + 1 в самый конец кода, и будет вам счастье.</strike>

UPD: Поставьте начальный максимум не 0, а -1. Это гарантирует, что максимум обновится по крайней мере 1 раз для первого элемента.

PS: И, кстати, не стоит использовать max в качестве имени переменной - это <strike>зарезервированное слово</strike> имя встроенной функции. В вашем коде это ничего не ломает, но если вы такое сделаете в реальном большом проекте, могут быть разные забавные спецэффекты, которые принесут немало седых волос вам или другим людям, работающим над тем же проектом.

Comment: Если ответ помог - вы можете отметить его как решение, нажав галочку рядом с ним, и добавить один бал, нажав на стрелочку вверх.

Comment: Не совсем понял зачем добавлять в конец n = e + 1, ведь тогда программа теряет весь смысл и работает неправильно, может я не так понял?

Comment: Я имею в виду - прямо перед выводом результата. Просто сейчас вы делаете n = e + 1 каждый раз, когда обновляете максимум. А если у вас максимум не обновляется ни разу (это как раз случай, когда у всех налог нулевой), то n = e + 1 вообще никогда не выполняется. На самом же деле вам нужно выполнить n = e + 1 всего один раз - перед самым выводом результата. Тогда это в любом случае будет выполнено ровно один раз.

Comment: Если я как вы говорите добавлю n = e +1 непосредственно перед выводом, то он же будет просто счетчиком того, сколько раз выполнится цикл, или я опять не догоняю?

Comment: Да, вы правы... Просто у вас в вопросе отступы в коде сбиты, и я немного запутался, что у вас к чему относится. Тогда сделайте так: начальный максимум сделайте не 0, а -1. Это гарантирует, что у вас максимум обновится хотя бы один раз для первого элемента и проблема решится.

Comment: Спасибо большое, прошло все тесты.

Comment: Пожалуйста, рад был помочь )

Comment: Позвольте уточнить в вашем ответе, что max – это не зарезервированное слово (keyword), а идентификатор встроенной функции (built-in function). И зарезервированные слова нельзя использовать в другом контексте, кроме как предусмотренном правилами языка, в отличии от идентификаторов встроенных функций – которые можно свободно переопределять, как в примере автора.

Comment: @MaximSize, действительно, неудачно выбрал термин. Спасибо за уточнение.